# Zabbix web scenario debug

Tags: zabbix

To figure out the problems in web scenario I need to check values of variables (macros) in some steps. I expect view in Web interface...

Comment: You should avoid multiple questions in a single post. For most of them you can find the answer in the official documentation (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/web_monitoring)

Comment: Increase log level for `http poller` - https://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-2-4-features-part-6-runtime-loglevel-changing/3653/ and watch zabbix server logs

Comment: nice, but i don't have access to system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently log is accessible only from system, but there is an ugly workaround to view variables:

1. Add step to not existing `URL` with variable in path, for example:

   https://{HOST.DNS}/{some_variable}/{some_other_variable}
2. server probably return error page, but you can set is as expected in `Required status codes`
3. set `Required string` to an not existing on error page, for example "not existing string"
4. then in details of web scenario you can see status:

> Error: required pattern "not existing string" was not found on https://some.dns/some_variable_value/some_other_variable_value

Comment: This is a pretty clever hack.